# How can I change the bash screen resolution to custom values?

Tags: boot, setup, screen, settings

I installed archlinux-arm on the RPI.

I have a TV, which has 1680x1050 resolution. Where can I change the bash settings to fit the screen correctly? I also want to the boot screen (where I can see what is loading) to be nice.

---

I have this [TV](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Syncmaster-225MW-inch-pixels/dp/B000R5G322). Which is the correct settings for this in the `config.txt`?

Comment: Just to be correct in terminology - there are no bash settings related to resolution as bash doesn't care about that. All it knows about is text. Now how big the text is and how many characters can you fit on the screen depends on _terminal_ settings. There are couple of terminals you can use - one is the "startup" one, which uses full screen framebuffer (this is the one you see before using startx) and the other can be run as window in graphical environment. What PhonicUK said tells you how to change framebuffer resolution which is used to display (almost) all the graphical output of RPi.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. In the `/boot/config.txt` file, add `hdmi_group=2` and `hdmi_mode=58` to get 1680x1050. You must be `root` to do this.
2. Restart the Raspberry Pi; `sudo reboot`.

#### Notes

See http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt for a complete list of resolutions and modes.

Comment: It dosent matter if I set the value of `hdmi_mode=` to 9, 16, or 35, the screen resolution stays the same. Why?

Comment: Have you verified that your changes are actually being saved to the file? Also can your display verify what the input resolution is, if so - what is it? Also make sure you have the hdmi_group=2 setting.

Comment: Yes, Im sure I set the `hdmi_group=2`, and the changes are surely saved. But how do you mean that input verify stuff?

Comment: Most displays have a 'info' screen that will tell you information about the input signal, including details about the screen resolution and refresh rate. Also neither of those values you said you used were the one I suggested. Try 58 and 57.

Comment: Despite any value I set to `hdmi_mode` the resolution stays the same. I tried with 58 and 57, and the resolution stays about 640x480 or something like this. I've got this, if matters http://www.amazon.co.uk/Samsung-Syncmaster-225MW-inch-pixels/dp/B000R5G322

Comment: Have you restarted the system?

Comment: If this hasn't solved your problem yet, why have you accepted it?

Comment: I sure reboot. I accepted this, because i thought It solved my problem, because the answer is correct where I should set the config. On the other hand I cant find the correct value for my TV.

Comment: Can you pastebin the contents of your config.txt?

Comment: `hdmi_group=2` \n
`hdmi_mode=58`

Comment: Are you using just straight HDMI, or are you using a HDMI->DVI connector somewhere? (Try using one if you're not, or not using one if you are)

Comment: straight hdmi. i will try then. ok

Comment: With `HDMI > DVI` it works well. Why not with straight HDMI?

Comment: I'd guess your TV is derp.

Answer (score 0):

I can explain what I think. In the config file have you 'uncommented' meaning to remove the # from a specific line. If u do not do this the Pi wont think any changes have been made.

[Also here is a link to a resolution spreadsheet.](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt)